# How to get list of drive letters in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to get a list of drive letters in a drop-down menu. I'm currently using the code below and it works just fine in Windows 10, but doesn't work at all in Windows 7.

```
     $Drive_Letters = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk
     ForEach ($Drives in $Drive_Letters.DeviceID) { $Dest_Drive_Box.Items.Add($Drives) }
```

In Win 7 I tried adjusting the code to this...

```
     $Drive_Letters = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID
     ForEach ($Drives in $Drive_Letters) { $Dest_Drive_Box.Items.Add($Drives) }
```

But now it shows "@DeviceID=C:}", "@DeviceID=D:}", etc. in Win 7 and 10 for each drive letter. I need to just show "C:", "D:", etc.

Thanks!

Comment: `Select-Object DeviceID` -> `Select-Object -Expand DeviceID`

Comment: Thanks Mathias! I forgot about `-Expand`. Seems to work in 7 and 10.

Answer (score 10):

```
Get-PSDrive
```

This will return all drives mapped in the current session.  The `Name` property contains the drive letter.

To capture just drive letters:

```
(Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[a-z]$'
```

Tested working in PSv2:

```
Get-PSDrive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' | Select-String -Pattern '^[a-z]$'
```

Comment: `-replace 'on your device','in the current session'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen True.  It captures most use cases, however.  I updated my answer

Comment: Also worth noting that `Get-PSDrive` includes _PS-specific_ drives, which outside programs won't see.

Comment: Thanks, however `Get-PSDrive` seems to return more than just drive letters. I see that each of the drive letters has a Provider value of "FileSystem", but I can't seem to narrow it down in Win 7 to just the drive letters.

Comment: @sloppyfrenzy `(Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[a-z]$'`

Comment: Instead of matching the name on a regex, just check where `Provider.Name -eq 'FileSystem'` -- e.g.: `Get-PSDrive | ? { $_.Provider.Name -eq 'FileSystem' } | % { $_.Root };`

Comment: How to get the main drive which is usually drive letter C?

Comment: @tarekahf You're looking for `$Env:SystemDrive` which reflects the drive Windows is installed on.

Answer (score 2):

```
$drives = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Root
```

returns an array for drives with the root path:

```
C:\
D:\
E:\
```

You can easily trim the ending if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_Logicaldisk | % {$_.DeviceId}
$Drives | % {$Dest_Drive_Box.Items.Add($_)}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are often unhelpful in pointing to why the issue happened. Please consider including an explanation why your code solves the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

It would appear that each item `$drives` is a HashTable with one Key-Value Pair `DeviceID = driveletter` a quick test shows that using `$Drives.DeviceID` returns just the value of the key-value pair.

```
ForEach ($Drives in $Drive_Letters) { $Dest_Drive_Box.Items.Add($Drives.DeviceID) }
```

Comment: Thanks, is this with or without `Select-Object DeviceID`? Can't seem to get it to work either way. Says it's a null-valued expression.

Comment: I did it with `Select-Object`